# Used to have Dual Boot what happened?

Tags: windows-10, multi-boot

I used to have dual boot linux and windows 10, but after an update I never figured what happened to it, is there a way to figure that out? That is partly due since the dual boot screen stopped appearing. Because I had it setup, and would like to delete the second OS. Any thoughts? I remember I had to go into the BIOS, but is there a way to setup a second OS, and boot it from inside windows 10 OS.

Comment: Windows 10 is known for wiping dual boot configurations with updates.

Comment: @S.S.Anne Thanks I was like so confused when that happened its been months now but I was hoping to install Linux in a safe manner is that possible? Like have it in Windows 10, and by chance is that called a Virtual Machine? Because I read these ideas like this one, and am wondering if they are safe, and won't get deleted https://itsfoss.com/install-linux-in-virtualbox/.

Comment: Please boot from a Linux LiveUSB, connect to the web, then open a terminal window, and run _sudo lshw -short -C disk ; lsblk | grep -v  loop  ; df -h | grep -v loop ; sudo blkid_ then highlight the resulting text, copy with Ctrl-Shift-C , then open a web browser, return here, click [edit] , and paste that text into the question, so we can see the structure of your drive(s).

Comment: @K7AAY I don't have Linux anymore its gone, I would have to reinstall it, which is why I am looking for a method.

Comment: Notice LiveUSB. Write this file to a USB or CD using a disk writer tool and boot it https://cdimage.debian.org/debian-cd/current-live/i386/iso-hybrid/debian-live-10.4.0-i386-standard.iso

Comment: For an Ubuntu LiveUSB, download the ISO file at https://ubuntu.com/download or for a supported 'flavour' with a different Desktop Environment, download from https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours . Next, check for download errors by https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-how-to-verify-ubuntu . Make a LiveUSB following these instructions on a Windows PC https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-windows